# Can I plug in array values into a image drawing function of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I wanted to created a row of the same picture like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrWl7.jpg

Where every grass picture is 70x70 pixels. I wanted to create this using a for loop and an array which stored 25 values. This is that code:

```
var pic = new Image()
var picture = pic.src = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXEODf7WhGahJl_eRIh5Np063DS1MtQhjem1NDJLfdFB2am4YB";

var grassXs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    grassXs.push(i*70);
}

for (var i = 0; i < grassXs.length;i++) {
    pic.addEventListener("load", function () {
        board.drawImage(pic,grassXs[i],430,70,70)
    }, false)
}
```

But for some reason it dosen't work at all. It dosen't create a single image. Is it possibily because  the paramters don't allow "taking" values from arrays? Or is it just something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give your grass image time to load.

You can do that using the `onload` callback on the image object.

Quick example:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var count=25;
var width=70;
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXEODf7WhGahJl_eRIh5Np063DS1MtQhjem1NDJLfdFB2am4YB";
function start(){
  canvas.width=width*count;
  canvas.height=img.height;
  for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    ctx.drawImage(img,i*width,0,width,img.height);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[ Additional explanation about your code ]**

For example, your code will execute in the following order:

```
// a new image object is created
var pic = new Image()

// "pic" BEGINS to load, but is not yet fully loaded
//       and is not yet ready to draw
var picture = pic.src = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXEODf7WhGahJl_eRIh5Np063DS1MtQhjem1NDJLfdFB2am4YB";

// This code is immediately executed even though
// "pic" has not yet fully loaded
var grassXs = [];

// This entire loop is immediately executed even though
// "pic" has not yet fully loaded
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    grassXs.push(i*70);
}

// This entire loop is immediately executed even though
// "pic" has not yet fully loaded
// Since "pic" is not fully loaded each "drawImage" below is
// drawing empty images onto the canvas
for (var i = 0; i < grassXs.length;i++) {
    // pic is being given 25 event handlers which all point
    // to the final value of "i". Since grassXs[25] is undefined 
    // all of the drawImages are ineffective
    pic.addEventListener("load", function () {
        board.drawImage(pic,grassXs[i],430,70,70)
    }, false)
}

// about this time (or later if the "pic" is a large image)
// "pic" is fully loaded and is now ready to drawImage with.
// Unfortunately, all the "drawImage"s have been executed with 
// invalid grassXs.
```

Comment: But what was the problem with mine? I understand that it was very unnecessary for me to run a pic.onload function each time the second for loop (the one that creates all the images) and then drawing and image; but why didn't it work? Is it because I can't access the variable I because I off the onload function in the loop?

Comment: @Axeowny. I've added a commented version of your code to show why you need `onload` to wait for `pic` to be fully loaded and fully drawImage-able. About your loop:  `pic` is being given 25 event handlers which all point to the final value of "i" (==25). Since `grassXs[25]` is undefined all of the `drawImage`s are ineffective.

Comment: Ohh and what you have done is that you execute everything that is linked with the image after the image has laoded by calling the function for the image-"properties" when the image has loaded. That is incredibly helpful, and if I had 15 in reputation you sir would be given an upvote!

Comment: You're welcome...glad I could help. Preloading app images before the app "begins processing" is very useful and certainly avoids some aggravating debugging later on. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You have a made a ["closure mistake"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake).
To sum up the above link, when you create a function object (in this case your event callback), it "remembers" its context (in this case the variable `i`) and not the values directly.
The problem is that in your loop, the variable `i` changes. And when the `onload` event is dispatched (well after the end of the loop), `i` has a value of 25.
In consequence `board.drawImage(pic,grassXs[25],430,70,70)`(notice the 25) is called 24 times when the image is loaded. And `grassXs[25]` is `undefined`. That's why nothing is displayed.

**Why is `i` 25 and not 24 ?**
Because the for loop will execute your code (and increment `i`) until the condition `i<24` is false. When it stops, `i` has been incremented to 25.
And when your callback is executed, `i` is still 25.

The easiest way to fix this is to correct another flaw in your code. What you are doing is that you are registering 24 `EventListener`s for the same event on your image object, with a callback function to draw one image each.
I have not tested the performance, but a simpler thing to do would be to register one EventListener with a callback function that draws the 24 images.

```
pic.addEventListener("load", function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < grassXs.length;i++) {
    board.drawImage(pic,grassXs[i],430,70,70);
  }
}, false)
```

Furthermore, your two for loops have exactly the same condition (`grassXs.length` is 25 after your first loop) so you could combine them by making the multiplication by 70 in the second loop. Here is a corrected version of your complete code :

```
var pic = new Image()
var picture = pic.src = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSXEODf7WhGahJl_eRIh5Np063DS1MtQhjem1NDJLfdFB2am4YB";

var count = 25;
pic.addEventListener("load", function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < count;i++) {
    board.drawImage(pic,i*70,430,70,70);
  }
}, false)
```

---

### How to deal with closures

In case you have another problem with closure in the future here is how you could have corrected this if there had not been an easier way. You should read the page at the link I posted above, but here is an example with your code.

You can either decide to put the code inside an external function and call this function with `i` as parameter :

```
function setListener(offset)
{
    pic.addEventListener("load", function () {
        board.drawImage(pic,offset,430,70,70);
    }, false) ;   
}

for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    setListener(i*70);
}
```

Or you can use a self-executing anonymous function, (in your case I would use the first way, until you are more experienced with the language.).

```
for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    (function(offset) {
        pic.addEventListener("load", function () {
            board.drawImage(pic, offset,430,70,70);
        }, false);
    })(i);
}
```

You wrap the function in parenthesis and pass the argument between parenthesis as if you were calling a normal function.